# javascript / internet explorer 8 crazyness

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I have a web page with javascript in it, everywhere it runs fine except ie8. When I load on IE8 my javascript is missing, so I turn on the developer tools and javascript console to debug it, refresh, and my javascript loads. It seems it only loads when I have previously enabled the JavaScript console.

Can anybody shed some light on this? You can view the page here

http://www.orchestra-agency.com/contentviewer_beta.php?cv=ORC_TWL_01&p=0

Comment: Do you use any debugger features, like logging to the console? This would introduce a dependancy. I don't know IE8, but that would be true for Firefox's Firebug, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Does the page make any `console` calls, like `console.log('foo')`, without first making sure that `console` and `console.log` are defined?

- A simple workaround: [`log()` – A lightweight wrapper for `console.log`](http://paulirish.com/2009/log-a-lightweight-wrapper-for-consolelog/)
- More powerful version: [JavaScript Debug: A simple wrapper for `console.log`](http://benalman.com/projects/javascript-debug-console-log/)

Comment: Yeah, it looks like that was the problem. Why oh why would internet explorer not be able to deal with that? I commented the logs out and it seems to work fine now. Thanks for a prompt responce.

Comment: Because IE is a miserable browser for web developers, always and forever. You need _something_ to be the bane of your existence, don't you? `:P` anyway, since your problem is solved, you should consider [accepting the most useful answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: IE8 doesn't create the console object unless you actually create a console, by opening the developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work in FF without Firebug enabled? If not, I'd bet it's the console.log's that cause it.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading this on the page header

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// IE fix
if(!window.console) {
    var console = {
        log : function(){},
        warn : function(){},
        error : function(){},
        time : function(){},
        timeEnd : function(){}
    }
}
</script>
```

It removes the functionality of any console code you have. If it fixes the problem, you have to find and clean all of them from your code...

This happens when the browser tries to output to the console but it doesn't exist so it throws an exception and blocks all further javascript.... :S